# What causes MARSHALLINGERROR when creating a znode?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am doing a simple `createAsync()` with my `ZooKeeperNetEx` nuget package and it is throwing an exception which is triggered by a `MARSHALLINGERROR`.

Here's is the two-line summary (between these lines, the connection successfully confirmed to Zookeeper):

```
  var Zoo = new ZooKeeper("localhost:50002", 5000, new ClusterWatcher());
  . . .
  var parentNode = Zoo.createAsync("/election", null, null, CreateMode.PERSISTENT).Result
```

I do not get it.  `ClusterWatcher` is my own class derived from `Watcher`, of course.   Yes, I am writing this in C# but this such a simple matter, I would not think it mattered.  The host machine is running Windows 10 Pro, if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

This exception can be triggered by not specifying the ACL mode (you seem to pass `null`). In Java you can pass the predefined list `ZooDefs.Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE` (for example, or one of the others in that class) for the ACL mode; for C# there will probably be a similarly named constant.

In the Java client library this is a convenience constant that is defined as:

```
/**
 * This is a completely open ACL .
 */
public final ArrayList<ACL> OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE = new ArrayList<ACL>(
        Collections.singletonList(new ACL(Perms.ALL, ANYONE_ID_UNSAFE))
);
```

Comment: Ids is available in ZookeeperNetEx in org.apache.zookeeper.ZooDefs.Ids.